# No Windows partition available after installing Ubuntu 14 LTS

Tags: grub2, partitioning, mount, ntfs

After an upgrade of Ubuntu from 12 LTS to 14 LTS version GRUB failed to boot.
With a boot repair disk ISO on my USB pen drive I found the Windows partition still exists and could be mounted, but the Data partition was not able to be mounted. Here the message from the system when I tried to open it:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/ubuntu/DATA_7: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/ubuntu/DATA_7"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (427606008): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

How can fix this problem and mount it again? There are a lot of jobs over there...

Comment: If an NTFS volume is damaged, that damage must be repaired in Windows by Windows utilities; Linux lacks any meaningful NTFS repair utility. (The `ntfsfix` tool just does some minimal checks and flags the filesystem as needing attention in Windows.)

Comment: It looks like your hard drive is damaged...    can you do a `sudo apt-get install smartmontools` and then a `smartctl --all /dev/sdb`, [edit] your question and add the output?

Comment: After upgrade, GRUB fails to boot Windows, or GRUB fails to boot Ubuntu? Instead of trying a "boot repair disk ISO", maybe you should try an Ubuntu live disk ISO on your USB pen drive.